Consecutive visits takes time to reset
I had 13 days of consecutive visits to the main site. I just checked this morning when going to Stack Overflow, to see if I visited it yesterday (wasn't sure).
I see I always had 13 consecutive days, but I saw I missed a day:

A few minutes later, I saw that I was set back to 1 day consecutive.
Is the site waiting for us to log into the site to break our consecutive visits? Is that possible to make it instantly break the number instead of faking?

I guess it's probably caching. Even if that's not the case no one other than you and the moderators can actually see that consecutive visits / calendar. Even if updating it is delayed to when someone checks that info it would not really be a problem.

You don't need to log in or out at all to maintain a streak. You only need to visit the site each day, where AFAIK "day" begins and ends at midnight UTC. Well, you need to log in once if you aren't already.

It's quite possible that the fact you loaded the site today, forced a recalculation.
The measure of "consecutive visits" is only visible from your own profile page. It doesn't make technical sense to keep that updated, real-time, for all users all over SE (Way too much load). A more efficient method is to only update that on demand, when requested.
So, what I think what happened here, is:

You visited the site for 13 consecutive days. This number is cached somewhere.
You didn't visit the site on the 14th. "13" was still cached.
You visited the site on the 15th. "13" was displayed and your visit was registered, updating the cache to reset to 1.
On reload, the profile page now shows the new value of "1".


The issue seems here it counted for the 15th, but didn't updating cache right now, or at least didn't change the showed value

What do you mean "it counted for the 15th"?

I mean, it takes in count the visit of the 15th day

It didn't? You say it said 13 consecutive days.  April 1st until April 13th is 13.

In the calendar, it were well showing the actual day as active

Yes, but the "X consecutive days" is on your profile page itself. The calendar display and that counter aren't necessarily directly linked. The counter is probably cached, and the calendar is probably not, as that's data you only load very rarely, when you click on the counter.
